# How to capture a maximized window accurately?

Tags: winapi, win32gui

- Refer to [WebRTC desktop_capture](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/modules/desktop_capture), I have been able to capture non-maximized window images successfully and accurately, but I encounter problems when capturing maximized windows on my win10: whether use BitBlt or PrintWindow, the boundary of the result has a few pixels black.
- I analyzed it, The root cause is that when I maximize it, I don’t know how to get the area corresponding to the visual window rectangle on GetWindowDC. The test found that the relative positions obtained by GetWindowRect and DwmGetWindowAttribute(...DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUND), GetCroppedWindowRect are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**whether use BitBlt or PrintWindow, the boundary of the result has a few pixels black.**

[GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect):

> In Windows Vista and later, the Window Rect now includes the area
> occupied by the drop shadow.
>
> Calling GetWindowRect will have different behavior depending on
> whether the window has ever been shown or not. If the window has not
> been shown before, GetWindowRect will not include the area of the drop
> shadow.
>
> To get the window bounds excluding the drop shadow, use
> DwmGetWindowAttribute, specifying DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS. Note
> that unlike the Window Rect, the DWM Extended Frame Bounds are not
> adjusted for DPI. Getting the extended frame bounds can only be done
> after the window has been shown at least once.

**The test found that the relative positions obtained by GetWindowRect and DwmGetWindowAttribute(...DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUND), GetCroppedWindowRect are not correct.**

The `GetCroppedWindowRect` function is actually a wrapper for `GetWindowRect`.

```
bool GetCroppedWindowRect(HWND window,
                          bool avoid_cropping_border,
                          DesktopRect* cropped_rect,
                          DesktopRect* original_rect) {
  DesktopRect window_rect;
  if (!GetWindowRect(window, &window_rect)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (original_rect) {
    *original_rect = window_rect;
  }
  *cropped_rect = window_rect;
  bool is_maximized = false;
  if (!IsWindowMaximized(window, &is_maximized)) {
    return false;
  }
```

`DwmGetWindowAttribute()` returns physical coordinates, and `GetWindowRect()` returns logical coordinates.

> Windows Vista introduces the concept of physical coordinates. Desktop
> Window Manager (DWM) scales non-dots per inch (dpi) aware windows when
> the display is high dpi. The window seen on the screen corresponds to
> the physical coordinates. The application continues to work in logical
> space. Therefore, the application's view of the window is different
> from that which appears on the screen. **For scaled windows, logical and
> physical coordinates are different**.

Refer: [PhysicalToLogicalPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-physicaltologicalpoint#remarks)

Comment: I will try DwmGetWindowAttribute for coordinate conversion on my win10; But Aero is not enabled on my win7: the function "DwmGetWindowAttribute(...DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUND)" return FALSE

Comment: @fredirty2017 If Desktop Composition has been disabled (Windows 7 and earlier), then this function returns DWM_E_COMPOSITIONDISABLED. Refer [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmsetwindowattribute#return-value).

Comment: @fredirty2017 Hi, if the answer is useful to you, don't forget to mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)